# Why does Visual Studio respect 'OutputPath', but MSBuild doesn't?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, teamcity

I have my filesystem as follows:

Solution Directory
-SolutionFile.sln
-Project One Directory
--ProjectOne.csproj
-Project Two Directory
--ProjectTwo.csproj

If I modify ProjectOne.csproj file to have the following, I get a 'binny' directory under my 'Project One' directory:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'OCTOPUS|AnyCPU'">
<OutputPath>.\binny</OutputPath>
<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
<ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When TeamCity runs my build, I don't get a 'binny' directory anywhere, and it looks like 'Project One' gets output to a 'bin' directory under the solution folder.  I'm sure the property group condition is correct, if I change 'OCTOPUS|AnyCPU', I get an error.

Why is there no 'binny' directory, do I need to use some other property?

Comment: Try setting your output to diagnostic, then compare the logs between visual studio and msbuild to see why there is a difference.

Comment: @Nick set my output to diagnostic for MSBuild?  How do I do that?

Comment: Tools -&gt; Options -&gt; Projects and Solutions -&gt; Build and Run, set "MsBuild Project Build Output Verbosity" to diagnostic (ignore the first one as it applies to C++ projects), then display the output window.  For MsBuild.exe, add a switch for a file logger to pipe the output to the file logger.  Use "/fl1 /flp1:Verbosity=diag;logfile=msbuild.log" then view msbuild.log.

Comment: Your setting of `OutputPath` only works if the compilation meets the condition of `OCTOPIS|AnyCPU`. Otherwise, MSBuild uses other `OutputPath` which seems to be `bin`. Thus, before posting such questions, make sure you fully understand how MSBuild.exe evaluates the script files. @Nick's advice is what you should follow, as log file can show you enough information to further troubleshoot.

Comment: Or TeamCity might overrule the OutputPath from the commandline, in which case the commandline wins.